# Copy all files in subfolders into new folder

Tags: vb.net, file-copying

I've been searching the net and have found a lot of posts about copying files, but I haven't had luck with copying files in subfolders. What I want to do is give a sourcePath, and a destinationPath. All files (including the ones in subfolders) will get copied into the destinatioPath. I've fiddled with lots of code but I haven't been able to get the search for subfolder to work.

Code I tried: but gives me an error on "dest" in the file copy line.

```
Public Sub CopyAllFiles(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)
    Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(destPath)

    For Each file As String In files
        ' Do work, example            
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file))
        file.Copy(file, dest, True)  ' Added True here to force the an overwrite 
    Next
End Sub
```

Code I tried but it moves the subfolder over to the desinationPath

```
    Public Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destinationPath As String)
    Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)

    ' If the destination folder don't exist then create it
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
    End If

    Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
    For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
        Dim destinationFileName As String =
        System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileSystemInfo.Name)

        ' Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
        If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, True)
        Else
            ' Recursively call the mothod to copy all the neste folders
            CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried this code buy it didn't give the files in the subfolders

```
Private Function CopyDirectory(sourcedir As String, targetdir As String, overwrite As Boolean) As List(Of String)
    Dim failedCopy As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetdir)

    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In files
        Dim newfile = file.Replace(sourcedir, targetdir)
        Dim fi = New FileInfo(file)
        Try
            fi.CopyTo(newfile, overwrite)
        Catch ex As Exception
            failedCopy.Add(file)
        End Try

    Next
    Return failedCopy
End Function
```

Comment: Would this help you ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @AndrewMortimer No it copies the whole subfolder over into the new location. I want to get all the files in the subfolders and main folder into a new location

Comment: @MaxineHammett how would you handle the case where two identically named files are in two different sub folders?

Comment: @djv that's a really good question and one of the problems. I would want the graphic in the subfolder to over write the graphic in the main folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you fairly close

```
Private Sub DirTestCopyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DirTestCopyButton.Click

    Try
        CopyDirectoryContents("c:\temp\", "c:\out")
        MessageBox.Show("Copy complete")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub CopyDirectoryContents(sourcePath As String, destinationPath As String)

    If Not Directory.Exists(sourcePath) Then
        Return
    End If

    If Not Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
    End If

    For Each filePathString As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim fileInfoItem As New FileInfo(filePathString)
        Dim newFilePath As String = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileInfoItem.Name)
        If File.Exists(newFilePath) Then
            'do something about this 
        Else
            File.Copy(filePathString, newFilePath)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That was awesome!